# get 100 with the help of five 2

Tags: arithmetic

how to get 100 with the help of +, -, /, * and five 2s?

22222 = 100

I should put arithmetic operants between two s and get 100. PLease help

Comment: Are you allowed to append twos, as in $22+22*2$? Otherwise there is definitely not a solution.

Comment: @SBareS yes, I am

Comment: I can't find a solution even allowing this! I can find an obvious one if we have $6$ of them though.

Comment: @fretty, yes it would be easy, if there were 6 of them

Comment: It would be easy with power operator.

Comment: I'm gonna say we need the power operator.

Comment: Have you tried a brute force solution with a computer? It shouldn't take impossibly long here.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta what do you mean? How do you do that?

Comment: Well it is just a case of trying each of the finitely many operations in each "gap". Simple to just check each one.

Comment: There are 4 spots between pairs of 2's where you can place an operator or nothing (nothing would mean 22 or 222) so there are $5^4$ options to iterate through.

Comment: @JohnyStark, grouping the five twos in all possible ways, applying all allowed operations in all possible orders and seeing if 100 comes out.

Comment: yeah, that would take a lot :)

Comment: $$(\frac{22-2}{2})^2$$

Comment: I got it with five '9's though: (99*9+9)/9 = 100

Comment: @OfirSchnabel, that works, but powers were not allowed.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel power operator is not allowed :(

Comment: OK sorry :(....

Comment: Even if the power operator was allowed, you can't use parentheses.

Comment: this probably doesn't even work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be impossible without a sixth 2 or the power operation.
(If either were allowed, you could use `(222-22)/2` or `((22-2)/2)^2`.)
I assumed parentheses are allowed although they were not explicitly mentioned.
Disallowing them doesn't help reaching 100.

First, you have to group the twos into numbers.
Five twos (2,2,2,2,2) can't give more than 32, so it's not enough.
If you have a 222, the possible combinations are (222,2,2) and (222,22) and it's relatively easy to check that these don't give 100.
It's even easier to see that (2222,2) and (22222) don't work.

The grouping (22,22,2) doesn't work either.
If you first take a binary operation between 22 and 22, you are too far from 100.
If you first modify one of the 22s by the 2, you get 24, 20, 11 or 44, and none of these numbers together with 22 can give 100.

The only thing left is (22,2,2,2).
The three 2s can't make anything larger than 8 together, so in order to get anywhere near 100 you have to multiply the 22 with something (possibly after adding or subtracting something).
Multiplying 22 directly doesn't work: the first reasonably large multiple is `22*2*2=88` and you can't correct this into 100 with a single 2.

So we have to add or subtract something before multiplying.
But then we can only use two 2s for the multiplier (which has to be at least four to make the result big enough).
This leaves `(22+2)*2*2=96` and `(22-2)*2*2=80`, neither of which is 100.

Notes:
My grouping notation does not imply any particular order.
When carrying out the operations, it seems most convenient to start with the biggest number (like 22 or 222) and operating on it with other numbers (or their allowed combinations); this doesn't leave anything out.
It is of course possible that I have made a mistake somewhere – do let me know if there is something fishy left.

Comment: Brute force simulation gives the same result. The closest number you can get is actually 96.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible conclusions:
1) The question is ill-posed (what is the EXACT formulation of the question by the way?)
2) Play dumb: 2-22/22 = 1+0+0